# How to change the default text editor of GNOME?

Tags: debian, gnome

gedit is the default editor of GNOME, how do I change it?

I modified the file `/etc/gnome/defaults.list`, then rebooted the system, and it works.

Now the filename `defaults.list` becomes `gnome-mimeapps.list`. For more details, see [MIME](https://wiki.debian.org/MIME.)

Comment: Right click on any text file > Properties > Open with

Comment: This just changes the one type file format but not all other formats.

Comment: There is no default editor in gnome, this is a matter of file type/mime type associations so yes, if you want it for several formats you'll have to [override that via config files](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/default_applications)

Answer (score 11):

Right click on the text file you want to open, choose Properties and then Open with. You should find the various alternatives in the Recommended Software or Other Applications lists. Click the one you want and then the "Set as Default" button.

That's Ubuntu 16.04, Gnome version 3.18.2.

[image]

Comment: Has the "Set as Default" option been removed? Gnome 3.36.5.

Comment: Not sure how to check the version of gnome that I'm running, but it's there in Ubuntu 16.04.  In Ubuntu Mate 18.04, it's just a radio button to select the default.  I suspect you're got to have some relatively accessible means to set it.

Comment: See 'about' in the Gnome settings or open `/usr/share/gnome/gnome-version.xml` in a text editor. Could you update your answer with a screenshot (always helpful with GUI-related instructions!)?

Comment: @user598527 - HTH!

Comment: Thank you. I'll create a new question later as that option appears to be missing with newer versions.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find anymore the "Set as Default" button mentioned by Diagon. What worked for me:

Create/edit `~/.config/mimeapps.list`

Adjust as follows:

```
[Default Applications]
text/plain=sublime_text.desktop;
```

See also: [Gnome documentation](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mime-types-application-user.html.en)

Tested on Gnome 42